# Facing difficulty in creating Request Object in Front End Java Spring MVC, need to replicate following .NET-MVC code into java

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, frontend

I am developing a front end application using Java Spring-MVC, however I'm facing difficulties in creating Request Object for Hitting Web-Services as I did in .Net-MVC. Can anyone tell me the equivalent classes and methods  in Java for below given code.

I need to replicate these 2 methods from .Net-MVC to Java.

1st Method:

```
    private HttpWebRequest RequestObj { get; set; }
    public Stream DataStreamObj { get; set; }
    private RequestModel RequestModelObj { get; set;         

    public RequestGenerator(String WebserviceUrl)
    {
        RequestObj = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServiceURL"] + WebserviceUrl);
        RequestObj.Method = "POST";GenerateLoginRequest
        RequestObj.ContentType = "application/json";

        RequestModelObj = new RequestModel();
        RequestModelObj.ApiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"];
        RequestModelObj.DeviceId = Constant.AppConstants.ONE;

    }
```

2nd Method:

```
    private string CallWebservice(Dictionary<String, Object> RequestDict)
    {
        try
        {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)RequestDict["request"];
            RequestModel RequestModel = (RequestModel)RequestDict["requestData"];

            //Tell them the length of content
            string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestModel);
            byte[] ByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json);

            Request.ContentLength = ByteArray.Length;

            //Write content on stream
            Stream DataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
            DataStream.Write(ByteArray, 0, ByteArray.Length);
            DataStream.Close();

            //Initiate Call
            HttpWebResponse Response = GetWebResponse(Request);
            DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(DataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.

            Reader.Close();
            Response.Close();
            return responseFromServer;
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            var response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            return "";

        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestTemplate class is designed to call REST services, it should come as no surprise that its main methods are closely tied to REST’s underpinnings, which are the HTTP protocol’s methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, and OPTIONS. E.g. it’s methods are headForHeaders(), getForObject(), postForObject(), put() and delete() etc.

Read More and Source Code : Spring REST JSON Example
HTTP GET Method Example

1) Get XML representation of employees collection in String format

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllEmployeesXML(Model model) 
{
model.addAttribute("employees", getEmployeesCollection());
return "xmlTemplate";
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void getEmployees()
{
final String uri = 
"http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees.xml";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

System.out.println(result);
}
```

2) Get JSON representation of employees collection in String format

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllEmployeesJSON(Model model) 
{
model.addAttribute("employees", getEmployeesCollection());
return "jsonTemplate";
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void getEmployees()
{
final String uri = 
"http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees.json";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

System.out.println(result);
}
```

3) Using custom HTTP Headers with RestTemplate

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllEmployeesJSON(Model model) 
{
model.addAttribute("employees", getEmployeesCollection());
return "jsonTemplate";
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void getEmployees()
{
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", 
headers);

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, 
HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

System.out.println(result);
}
```

4) Get data as mapped object

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllEmployeesXML(Model model) 
{
model.addAttribute("employees", getEmployeesCollection());
return "xmlTemplate";
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void getEmployees()
{
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

EmployeeListVO result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, 
EmployeeListVO.class);

System.out.println(result);
```

}

5) Passing parameters in URL

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeVO> getEmployeeById (@PathVariable("id") 
int id) 
{
if (id <= 3) {
    EmployeeVO employee = new 
EmployeeVO(1,"Lokesh","Gupta","howtodoinjava@gmail.com");
    return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeVO>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
}
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void getEmployeeById()
{
final String uri = 
"http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees/{id}";

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", "1");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
EmployeeVO result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, EmployeeVO.class, 
params);

System.out.println(result);
}
```

HTTP POST Method Example

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeVO 
employee) 
{
System.out.println(employee);
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void createEmployee()
{
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees";

EmployeeVO newEmployee = new EmployeeVO(-1, "Adam", "Gilly", 
"test@email.com");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
EmployeeVO result = restTemplate.postForObject( uri, newEmployee, 
EmployeeVO.class);

System.out.println(result);
}
```

HTTP PUT Method Example

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeVO> updateEmployee(@PathVariable("id") 
int id, @RequestBody EmployeeVO employee) 
{
System.out.println(id);
System.out.println(employee);
return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeVO>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void deleteEmployee()
{
final String uri = 
"http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees/{id}";

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", "2");

EmployeeVO updatedEmployee = new EmployeeVO(2, "New Name", "Gilly", 
"test@email.com");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.put ( uri, updatedEmployee, params);
}
```

HTTP DELETE Method Example

REST API Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{id}", method = 
RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int 
id) 
{
System.out.println(id);
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

REST Client Code

```
private static void deleteEmployee()
{
final String uri = 
"http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees/{id}";

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", "2");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.delete ( uri,  params );
}
```